How to take screenshot in gtk4?
I am trying to take a screenshot of the root window in gtk4. This is how I do it in gtk3--
  GdkWindow *root_win = gdk_get_default_root_window();
  gint width = gdk_window_get_width(root_win);
  gint height = gdk_window_get_height(root_win);

  cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
  width, height);
  /*.........................*/

  cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "image.png");

But gdk_get_default_root_window function has been removed in gtk4. How to take a screen shot in Gtk4? Please do not recommend x11.

Gtk snapshot
